# Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am kinda desperated. Everytime when I try to `tns publish ios` I see this error. I can't build IPA file for App Store.

```
Archive at: /Users/roman/Desktop/eSports/PiratiGo/platforms/ios/build/archive/PiratiGo.xcarchive
2017-08-11 21:56:12.694 xcodebuild[44465:1369169] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/c8/kcxg82ln2mn7qy9v0rtppm8w0000gn/T/PiratiGo_2017-08-11_21-56-12.693.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-08-11 21:56:16.141 xcodebuild[44465:1369169] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fc68767cee0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"PiratiGo.app\" requires a provisioning profile.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"PiratiGo.app\" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Select a provisioning profile for the \"Default\" build configuration in the project editor.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: "PiratiGo.app" requires a provisioning profile.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""PiratiGo.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="PiratiGo.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Select a provisioning profile for the "Default" build configuration in the project editor.}
```

I really don't know what to do. I tried almost everything. Provision profile I have. Bud I dunno know why it doesn't see it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your best approach at this point would be to build the app for release as normal with the CLI and then open the platforms/ios project in Xcode (make sure to open the xcworkspace file instead of xcproject if there is one). Then fix the issues in Xcode - there's plenty of docs and SO issues to help with that (as from there on out it's not NativeScript related).

Once signing is fixed, you may want to try using `tns publish ios` again.